# NodeJS SSH authentication host and command execution

Tags: node.js, ssh

I want to have a NodeJS application to which I can connect over SSH with a public key and send some data to. To be more explicit it should go as follow:

- NodeJS application has some functions written
- From a server I ssh the nodejs application and tries to identify me by my public key
- After I am authenticated, I can send some strings to it, the app is going to parse the string and execute different functions

The only problem is that I cannot manage to do this with any SSH npm package existing. I want the nodejs app to just accept SSH connection and do the authentication and wait for some strings. Is this possible?

EDIT: I want to go with this approach because I only want to call the node functions to execute something only from some allowed clients (servers) and I don't want to send those requests via HTTP so anyone could access it

Comment: SSH usually lets you execute commands, which could be directed at your node app. Why do you want to do the SSH part in node?

Comment: because, instead of having some bash scripts that I run with params from SSH, I just want to execute some node functions that do multiple tasks. And instead of calling the node app from a server with HTTP requests, I would like to go for SSH type of connection as it is more secure. Because I only want to allow the requests to come from only a few allowed clients

Comment: HTTPS not good enough? Another option would be to set your node app up as the user's login shell :)

Comment: HTTPS is good enough. But my main problem is that I don't want the requests to come from any other IP than the one from a given server. So no one else could trigger the requests from any other IP. By now I'm using express to only allow requests from 1 IP. But in the feature, I must allow requests from other multiple servers that I own and this script will run on many other servers. Which will make this a mess to manage.

Comment: This app is going to be deployed on multiple servers/vps. So if I am going to update the allowed IP addresses, it would be a mess to get on each server/vps and update the allowed IP requests. That's why I'm looking into something like that, so I can authenticate by the public key.

Comment: You can authenticate by public key over HTTPS as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably better off using HTTPS with client certificates rather than using an SSH server within node (although you can do that with the [ssh](https://github.com/rvagg/node-libssh) module, a binding to libssh2), if you want to use certificates.

Here's how you'd set up the HTTPS server:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'), // server private key
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'), // server certificate
  ca: fs.readFileSync('server_ca.crt'), // server CA, this can be an array of CAs too
  requestCert: true
};

https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
  if (req.client.authorized) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Hello world!');
  } else {
    res.writeHead(401);
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(443);
```

Then it's just a matter of generating a client certificate using the server's CA that you use with your HTTPS client.

For connecting to the HTTPS server:

**For cURL**, the command line would look something like: `curl -v -s --cacert server_ca.crt --key client.key --cert client.crt https://localhost` or to skip server verification: `curl -v -s -k --key client.key --cert client.crt https://localhost`

**For node.js**, you might use client code like:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  // normal http.request()-specific options
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',

  // tls.connect()-specific options
  key: fs.readFileSync('client.key'), // client private key
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client.crt'), // client certificate
  ca: fs.readFileSync('server_ca.crt'), // server CA, this can be an array of CAs too
  // or comment out the `ca` setting and use the following to skip server verification,
  // similar to cURL's `-k` option:
  //rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.request(options, function(res) {
  if (res.statusCode === 200)
    console.log('Accepted!');
  else
    console.log('Rejected!');

  // drain and discard any response data
  res.resume();
}).end();
```